# Vim discrepancy between :!pwd and :pwd

Tags: vim

In my current vim environment, I'm trying to run some shell commands from the editor and they are failing because

```
:!pwd
```

is giving me some other specific directory.

```
:pwd
```

Gives the correct directory. I'm trying to figure out where the discrepancy is coming from.
I start vim from the command-line in the directory which I expect to see as the current working directory.
Any hints as to what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing two different commands (that happen to look similar).

The ! operator will always execute a shell and then execute the command line you specified.

The :pwd operator is a vim command.

When you execute the :pwd command the directory is relative to the vim environment. The ! operator is relative to how your shell is configured.

Comment: Doesn't vim allow :! commands to inherit its own working directory (as is the default everywhere)?

Comment: @grawity That's what I felt should be the case as well. 
Claris, my shell shows me the current working directory when I execute the command there, it is only showing me the incorrect directory when I execute the shell command from within vim. As I mentioned in the original post, I launch vim from the directory I expect to see in the output of !pwd and pwd. I'm using tcsh in case that is relevant here.

Comment: @Claris Your point of Vim executing a new shell cleared up what was happening. My cshrc file is changing to this default directory, and since vim is starting a new shell when I execute the shell command, it defaults to the directory from the cshrc. Thanks!